# HTML 5 (video.js 5) Video Playback on iPhone doesnt work

Tags: iphone, html, video.js

Hy community.

For some reasons, i must upload a Video to our website directly, and by this way, i tryed to protect the video from being downloaded.

Now, it works fine on most desktop browsers, and all android phones, but in 90% of cases, it doesnt work on iphone.

Can someone tell me why ?

Here is the original link to the video site (beta):
http://www.lunatics-carclub.at/includes/relaunch/aftermovie

The video is embed normally, but with 3 plugins. 
The first plugin is for a responsive video.js player.
The second is for a watermark, and the third for resolution switch.

Regards. Chris

Comment: How do you load the site on iPhone? Via `UIWebView`?

Comment: No specific iPhone tags etc. The site will be loaded via normal web-link, or shared facebook content.

Answer (score 0):

Especially given that the behaviour isn't 100% I'd think this is a timing issue. You've got two points in the code that the player could be initialised, and it's likely your switcher plugin isn't available when your script tries to use it if things happen in the order you're not expecting:

- The presence of the `data-setup` attribute at line 194
- The first `videojs()` on line 203

`videojs()` returns the player object if it isn't already initialised, or initialise it and return it if not. That's also why the options in the second `videojs()` on 220 are ignored, it's too late.

The ready functions will execute when the play is ready *or* immediately if the player is already ready.

You can probably resolve this by:

- removing the `data-setup` attribute as you only have placeholder options anyway.
- using the options you want to pass to the player in the first use of `videojs`, which would make sure your plugin is loaded.
- combining your ready functions into one may also help, or at least make it easier to troubleshoot.